# Show mark labels near marks and not centered in ybar interaval graph

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I'm doing a graph with vertical bars (ybar) where each bar represents not a number (1) but a class ([-0.5,0.5]).

I would prefer that tick labels on the x axis appeared near the ticks marks, so marking the limits of each interval/class and not how they actually appear, at the center of the bar. How can I do this?

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}

% ---------------------------------- tikz 
\usepackage{pgfplots}          % to print charts
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
%


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
      % general
      ybar interval,
      scale only axis,
      height=0.5\textwidth,
      width=\textwidth,
      ylabel={Dots numbers},
      xlabel={Variation},
      xticklabel style={
        rotate=90,
        anchor=east,
      },
      minor xtick={-6,...,6},
      enlargelimits=false,
      ]
      \addplot table [
        x=grade,
        y=value,
      ] {
grade   value
-7  0
-6  0
-5  3
-4  1
-3  2
-2  15
-1  11
0   179
1   8
2   1
3   0
4   1
5   2
6   0
7   0
      };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And the graph:

[image: ybar graph]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply a shift to the labels. I'd like to propose you, however, another approach presenting the labels as intervals. Below I show both alternatives:

```
\documentclass{article}

% ---------------------------------- tikz 
\usepackage{pgfplots}          % to print charts
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
%


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
      % general
      ybar interval,
      scale only axis,
      height=0.5\textwidth,
      width=\textwidth,
      ylabel={Dots numbers},
      xlabel={Variation},
      x tick label as interval=true,
      xticklabel={
$[\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick},\pgfmathprintnumber{\nexttick}\pgfmathparse{int(\tick)}\ifnum\pgfmathresult=6\relax]\else)\fi$
        },
      xtick=data,
      xticklabel style={
        rotate=90,
        anchor=east,
      },
      minor xtick={-6,...,6},
      enlargelimits=false,
      ]
      \addplot table [
        x=grade,
        y=value,
      ] {
grade   value
-7  0
-6  0
-5  3
-4  1
-3  2
-2  15
-1  11
0   179
1   8
2   1
3   0
4   1
5   2
6   0
7   0
      };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
      % general
      ybar interval,
      scale only axis,
      height=0.5\textwidth,
      width=\textwidth,
      ylabel={Dots numbers},
      xlabel={Variation},
      xticklabel style={
        rotate=90,
        anchor=south east,
        yshift=0.5*\pgfplotbarwidth
      },
      minor xtick={-6,...,6},
      enlargelimits=false,
      ]
      \addplot table [
        x=grade,
        y=value,
      ] {
grade   value
-7  0
-6  0
-5  3
-4  1
-3  2
-2  15
-1  11
0   179
1   8
2   1
3   0
4   1
5   2
6   0
7   0
      };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I had thought of that first approach, but (without seeing it) it didn't seem as easy to read.
However, that specific solution has a problem, since the last value of each interval is repeated: -6 appears in two classes. Even if corrected [-7,-6[,[-6,-5[, etc., the last interval class would have to be different (to close the set, [6,7]. Would that be possible?
I also find it strange that this specific style (ybar interval) doesn't address this auto of the box (I guess there is always space for improvement!)

Comment: @FernandoCésar Yes, it is possible. Please see my updated answer.